# How to change the translucence of ellipses in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, opacity, alpha

I'm making a plot with 100 different ellipses in ggplot2. I want the ellipses/polygons on the plot to be slightly translucent so that the areas with the most lines on them become darker, whereas areas with one ellipse would be quite faint.

[The opacity I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/422Lf.png) vs [the opacity im currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1tRM.png)

However, no matter what I change `alpha` to, it doesn't seem to have an effect? What am I doing wrong?

```
ggplot(data = cssibernobk, aes(iso1, iso2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Marlin Species", labels = c("Blue Marlin", "Striped Marlin"),values=c(col_list)) +
  geom_polygon(data = ellipse_dfcs,
               show.legend = FALSE,
               mapping = aes(iso1, iso2,
                             group = ellipse_dfcs$group,
                             color = factor(group),
                             fill = factor(group)), fill = NA, alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = col_list)+
  geom_point(colour="black", shape=21, size = 2, 
             aes(fill = factor(group))) + 
  ylab(expression(paste(delta^{34}, "S (\u2030)")))+ 
  xlab(expression(paste(delta^{13}, "C (\u2030)")))+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

I've added some data:

```
dput(cssibernobk[1:10,])
structure(list(iso1 = c(-19.0666624548854, -17.8943955612859, 
-18.9928609367509, -16.4710761874456, -18.2727144857982, -20.5069897964015, 
-20.5966996037602, -17.5454265065267, -16.4393689881177, -17.4617536511442
), iso2 = c(19.4934410976126, 19.2364832949763, 19.7701196888491, 
19.837594669008, 19.7147010622141, 20.3802264543413, 20.4655925249838, 
19.0895171633117, 19.7264242586365, 19.2537859386917), group = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), community = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

dput(ellipse_dfcs[1:10,])
structure(list(id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1"), iso1 = c(-15.3019878272902, -15.4740783680741, -15.6530442971316, 
-15.8381649818314, -16.0286950065133, -16.2238671740144, -16.4228955949008, 
-16.6249788519676, -16.8293032272625, -17.0350459786413), iso2 = c(20.3654052739855, 
20.44444500941, 20.5195305006846, 20.5903594050369, 20.6566465194678, 
20.718124929163, 20.7745470822651, 20.8256857866775, 20.8713351248865, 
20.9113112831188), community = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1"), group = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Cheers for the help!

Comment: Only some plotting devices accept transparent polygons. I often have this issue with an XQuartz plotting device. Have you tried plotting to `.png`?

Comment: I managed to plot transparent polygons in a really similar plot without plotting to .png so i figured it was a problem with the code! I'll try that and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: If that doesn't work, [edit] your question with some sample data with `dput(cssibernobk[1:10,])` and `dput(ellipse_dfcs[1:10,])` and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yeah couldn't make it work! I've added some sample data and also I'll add an example of what I'm trying to achieve, vs how it currently looks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't enough data points in the sample of `ellipse_dfcs` to plot more than a tiny bit. [Here is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPp5i.png) Maybe you could post more (or all) of the data on Github? Also, we don't have `col_list`, but it probably isn't necessary. It's getting late here, but I'll take a look in the morning if no one else has been able to help you.

Comment: `col_list` is just two different colours, sorry, should probably have made that clear! Also, looking at the data, the problem may be because my 100 Ellipses were stored as a list, and I used `bind_rows` to make it plotable. So it may not be recognizing it as 100 Ellipses but a single object. Not sure how to fix this though, might need to find a way to plot the Ellipses without binding them. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're specifying `alpha=`, but that gets applied to the `fill=`, not the `color=` of the line.  In `geom_line()`, for example, you can use `alpha=` to make the line transparent, but it's not the case with `geom_polygon()`.  Since it's hard to show using your set, let me demonstrate with an example set:

```
# I dunno, I'm making shapes...
d <- data.frame(id=c(rep('this',4),rep('that',4)), x=c(0,1,1,0.5,0.5,2,0.5,0.5), y=c(0,0,2,3,0.5,2,2,1))

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()
p + geom_polygon(aes(color=id), size=1.5)
```

[image]

Truly, there has never been a more beautiful picture.  If we apply `alpha=` to that, you'll see that only the fill is affected:

```
p + geom_polygon(aes(color=id), size=1.5, alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

So how do we fix it?  Well, you need to specify alpha another way, which is to use `alpha(): the function`.  You may think it could be possible to use within `aes()` and apply directly to the `color=` aesthetic... but you'd be wrong.  `aes(color=alpha(id, 0.2))` will not work, because `alpha()` expects to be sent the actual color name, not a factor name like `ggplot2`.  You can, however, specify `alpha()` within `scale_color_manual()`, which is where we arrive at our answer:

```
p + geom_polygon(aes(color=id), size=1.5, alpha=0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=alpha(c("this"='blue', "that"='red'),0.2))
```

[image]

It might be hard to see from that, but the colors for the lines are transparent.  You can compare to the same colors without the alpha setting:

```
p + geom_polygon(aes(color=id), size=1.5, alpha=0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("this"='blue', "that"='red'))
```

[image]

Should be obvious now that you'd need to change your `scale_color_manual()` line.  I think this should work:

```
  scale_color_manual(values = alpha(col_list, 0.2))
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly!!! Thanks heaps for the help.